# Edit a specific mysql row using php [re-edited]

Tags: php, sql

Edited the question again.

Here's my progress now, I transferred the code to another sheet and made it cleaner, no errors but still it's not updating my table. For those who responded at my previous question, thank you for being so kind.

Edit code.

```
"<a href=\"edit.php?id=". $row['ID'] ."\">Edit</a>". "</td>";
```

Here's my new edit.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="edit1.php">
    Components: <input type="text" name="Components"> <br /><br />
    Manufacturer: <input type="text" name="Manufacturer"> <br /><br />
    ManufacturerPN: <input type="text" name="ManufacturerPN"> <br /><br />
    Description: <input type="text" name="Description"> <br /><br />
    Quantity: <input type="number" name="Quantity"> <br /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br /><br />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the edit1.php

```
<?php 
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpass = "";
        $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $Components = $_POST['Components'];
    $Manufacturer = $_POST['Manufacturer'];
    $ManufacturerPN = $_POST['ManufacturerPN'];
    $Description = $_POST['Description'] ;
    $Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
    $id = $_GET['ID'];

    $sql= "UPDATE form SET Components='$Components' , Manufacturer='$Manufacturer' , ManufacturerPN='ManufacturerPN' , Description='$Description' , Quantity='Quantity' WHERE ID = '$id'";

    mysql_select_db('practice1');

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    if(!$result){
       die ('Could not enter data:' . mysql_error());
    }else if ($result){
        header("location:Inventory.php");
    }

}
?>
```

Am I at the correct path?

Comment: Avoid using mysql_* functions they are already deprecated .

Comment: I only have [PHP: 5.4.31], does this support mysqli_* already? Because I can't upgrade it anymore, I'm at windows xp.

Comment: But sure, I'll try. Thanks

Comment: One question : In your `<form>` value coming properly or not ? Or there itself error coming ? Or, after submitting form error comes ? Plz Tell.

Comment: yes, you should use mysqli_* instead of mysql_* and yes your php version supports mysqli_*

Comment: you give your variables `$components` etc. the value of isset(), which will be true or false. if you want to do a test first, use `$Components = (isset($_POST['Components'] ? $_POST['Components'] : somevalueyouwant);`

Comment: Same error mentioned above

Comment: As I already pointed in my answer below. There is no `$link` present in `mysql_select_db('practice1');`. And, you didn't followed it. This is the 3rd time you edited your question. Every time new functionality implemented in your code. *I'm voting it to close this question.*

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. There seems to be an issue with brackets.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<?PHP

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("practice1", $link);

    if(isset($_GET['ID']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['ID'];
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $Components = $_POST['Components'];
            $Manufacturer = $_POST['Manufacturer'];
            $ManufacturerPN = $_POST['ManufacturerPN'];
            $Description = $_POST['Description'];
            $Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];

            $query3 = mysql_query("UPDATE form set Components='$Components', Manufacturer='$Manufacturer' , ManufacturerPN='$ManufacturerPN' , Description='$Description' , Quantity='$Quantity' where ID=$id");
        if($query3){

            header("location:Inventory.php");

        }
        }


    }

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form where ID='$id'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

    ?>

        <form method="post" action="">

    Components: <input type="text" name="Components" value="<?php echo $row["Components"]?>"> <br /><br />
    Manufacturer: <input type="text" name="Components" value="<?php echo $row["Manufacturer"]?>"> <br /><br />
    ManufacturerPN: <input type="text" name="Components" value="<?php echo $row["manufacturerPN"]?>"> <br /><br />
    Description: <input type="text" name="Components" value="<?php echo $row["Description"]?>"> <br /><br />
    Quantity: <input type="number" name="Components" value="<?php echo $row["Quantity"]?>"> <br /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br /><br />

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already tried this but it shows Notice : Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\edit.php on line 6 in each of the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","", "dbName");
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql); // $sql = YOUR QUERY
// Numeric array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** 
Each `<input>` having same name. So,

Change

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    Components: <input type="text" name="Components"> <br /><br />
    Manufacturer: <input type="text" name="Components"> <br /><br />
    ManufacturerPN: <input type="text" name="Components"> <br /><br />
    Description: <input type="text" name="Components"> <br /><br />
    Quantity: <input type="number" name="Components"> <br /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br /><br />
</form>
```

To

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    Components: <input type="text" name="Components"> <br /><br />
    Manufacturer: <input type="text" name="Manufacturer"> <br /><br />
    ManufacturerPN: <input type="text" name="ManufacturerPN"> <br /><br />
    Description: <input type="text" name="Description"> <br /><br />
    Quantity: <input type="number" name="Quantity"> <br /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br /><br />
</form>
```

**2)** Change

```
$sql = "UPDATE form SET Components=$Components, Manufacturer=$Manufacturer , ManufacturerPN=$ManufacturerPN , Description=$Description , Quantity=$Quantity where ID=$id";
```

To

```
$sql = "UPDATE form SET Components='$Components', Manufacturer='$Manufacturer' , ManufacturerPN='$ManufacturerPN' , Description='$Description' , Quantity='$Quantity' WHERE ID=$id";
```

**3)** Change `mysql_select_db('practice1');` to `mysql_select_db('practice1', $link);`

**4)** Change

```
$Components = isset($_POST['Components']);
$Manufacturer = isset($_POST['Manufacturer']);
$ManufacturerPN = isset($_POST['ManufacturerPN']);
$Description = isset($_POST['Description']);
$Quantity = isset($_POST['Quantity']);
$id = isset($_GET['ID']);
```

To

```
$Components = $_POST['Components'];
$Manufacturer = $_POST['Manufacturer'];
$ManufacturerPN = $_POST['ManufacturerPN'];
$Description = $_POST['Description'];
$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
$id = $_GET['ID'];
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "";
  $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $db = mysql_select_db('practice1', $link);

  if (!$link){
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  $Components = $_POST['Components'];
  $Manufacturer = $_POST['Manufacturer'];
  $ManufacturerPN = $_POST['ManufacturerPN'];
  $Description = $_POST['Description'];
  $Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
  $id = $_GET['ID'];

   $sql = "UPDATE form SET Components='$Components', Manufacturer='$Manufacturer' , ManufacturerPN='$ManufacturerPN' , Description='$Description' , Quantity='$Quantity' WHERE ID=$id";

  $retval = mysql_query($sql, $link);

  if(!$retval){
      die ('Could not enter data:' . mysql_error());
  }
  header("location:Inventory.php");


  mysql_close($link);
} else {?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    Components: <input type="text" name="Components"> <br /><br />
    Manufacturer: <input type="text" name="Manufacturer"> <br /><br />
    ManufacturerPN: <input type="text" name="ManufacturerPN"> <br /><br />
    Description: <input type="text" name="Description"> <br /><br />
    Quantity: <input type="number" name="Quantity"> <br /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit"> <br /><br />
    </form>

<?PHP }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. You need to change in `<form>`. Because, each and every `input` is having same `name`. So, change it accordingly (as i gave) @LovelyGraceHernandez

Comment: Yeah there's no error now, but another problem occurred, the data isn't updating. :/

Comment: Do one thing. In Place of this line `$sql = "UPDATE form SET` Please write this line `echo "UPDATE form SET Components='$Components', Manufacturer='$Manufacturer' , ManufacturerPN='$ManufacturerPN' , Description='$Description' , Quantity='$Quantity' WHERE ID=$id"; die;` and whatever it is getting echoed. Copy the echoed code and paste in phpmyadmin directly in sql section and tell me the output/error @LovelyGraceHernandez

Comment: Use my updated code in place of your code. @LovelyGraceHernandez

Comment: Hello sir, still not updating. No errors but it doesn't updated the data.

Comment: Cross check each end everything. Check All column name , table name, database name. It's correct or not. And, please `echo "UPDATE form SET Components='$Components', Manufacturer='$Manufacturer' , ManufacturerPN='$ManufacturerPN' , Description='$Description' , Quantity='$Quantity' WHERE ID=$id"; die;` Tell me the output what it comes after echoing this statement @LovelyGraceHernandez

Comment: What happened ? You didn't responded  @LovelyGraceHernandez

Comment: It says query is empty sir

Comment: Lot of error is there in your code @LovelyGraceHernandez. See point 4.

Comment: yes sir, I revised my code again, it's cleaner now.